# restructure lists of lists by iteration in Python

Tags: python

I have a 2D list or list of lists.

Input file is

```
A       58.76-65.9
B       58.76-65.9
C       58.76-65.9
A       24.8-62.8
```

I then created a list of lists:

```
with open("Input.txt", "r") as file:
    raw = [[str(x) for x in line.split()] for line in file]

print (raw)
```

which returns

```
[['A', '58.76-65.9'], ['B', '58.76-65.9'], ['C', '58.76-65.9'], ['A', '24.8-62.8']]
```

---

My aim is to now create a new list of lists with a new structure. How can I obtain a new list of lits like this?

```
[['58.76-65.9', 'A', 'B', 'C'], ['A', '24.8-62.8']]
```

---

I first tried unioning sets, but that creates one large list and I need lists of lists. Therefore my plan is to (1) Create a new empty list of lists, 
(2) iterate through the original list of lists, 
(3) check if the 2nd element (i.e. 58.76-65.9) exists in the new list lists of lists. If it does not, extend both elements. If it does, just the first element (ie A)

```
# Defining empty list
matches=[]
# Accesing each row in the 2d list
for r in raw:
    if r[1] not in matches[0][]:
        matches.append([r[1], r[0]])
```

I realize that `matches[0][]` is not correct, what is the correct way to access it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the grouping idiom:

```
>>> data = [['A', '58.76-65.9'], ['B', '58.76-65.9'], ['C', '58.76-65.9'], ['A', '24.8-62.8']]
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> grouper = defaultdict(list)
>>> for x, y in data:
...     grouper[y].append(x)
...
>>> grouper
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'24.8-62.8': ['A'], '58.76-65.9': ['A', 'B', 'C']})
```

Now, I honestly think the above data-structure is much more practical, but you can easily convert into a list-of-lists if you really want:

```
>>> [[k] + v for k, v in grouper.items()]
[['24.8-62.8', 'A'], ['58.76-65.9', 'A', 'B', 'C']]
```

Or even nicer:

```
>>> [[k, *v] for k, v in grouper.items()]
[['24.8-62.8', 'A'], ['58.76-65.9', 'A', 'B', 'C']]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use the dictionary data structure. It does, what you want:

```
# Load data:
my_array = [[1 , 10], [2, 10], [3, 20]]
# Result as a dictionary:
result = {}
# Loop over data:
for value, key in my_array:
  if key not in result:
    # Create new list
    result[key]=[]
  result[key].append(value)
# If you really need a list of lists as output, do something like:
result_l = [list(elem) for elem in result.items()]
# (in python3)
```